# Learning to implement thread pool - signaled events getting lost when using autoresetevent

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety, autoresetevent, thread-synchronization

I am a strong believer in learning by reinventing. With that state of mind, I set out to implement custom thread pool. The objective that I set for myself was following:

1. To be able to queue work items on the thread pool.
2. To be able to process work items with fixed number of threads – all created at same time.
3. Common worker thread function should only know how to deque and should not deal with other functions/properties like
   IsEmpty or Count.

I succeeded in attaining the above mentioned objectives but want to validate the approach that I took with the experts on stackoverflow. Also, would like to learn if there are better approaches or how would an expert in multithreading would solve this problem. The following paragraphs mentioned about the challenge that I faced and how did I fixed it.

The thread pool that I created, internally maintained a queue of work items from which all the worker threads picked the item and then process it. Whenever a new item gets queued, it would signal an event so that any free thread can pick it up and execute it.

I started with autoresetevent to signal the waiting threads for any new work items on the queue, but I faced the problem of lost signaled events. It happens when more than one item gets queued and there are no free threads to process the item. The total items that remain unprocessed are same as the total signal events that are lost because of overlapping set (signaling) events.

In order to fix the problem of lost signaled events, I created a wrapper on top of autoresetevent and used it in place of autoresetevent. It fixed on the problem. Here is the code listing for the same:

```
public static class CustomThreadPool
{
    static CustomThreadPool()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < minThreads; i++)
            _threads.Add(
                new Thread(ThreadFunc) { IsBackground = true }
                );

        _threads.ForEach((t) => t.Start());
    }

    public static void EnqueWork(Action action)
    {
        _concurrentQueue.Enqueue(action);
        _enqueEvent.Set();
    }

    private static void ThreadFunc()
    {
        Action action = null;
        while (true)
        {
            _enqueEvent.WaitOne();
            _concurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out action);
            action();
        }
    }

    private static ConcurrentQueue<Action> _concurrentQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
    private static List<Thread> _threads = new List<Thread>();
    private static CountAutoResentEvent _enqueEvent = new CountAutoResentEvent();
    private static object _syncObject = new object();
    private const int minThreads = 4;
    private const int maxThreads = 10;

    public static void Test()
    {
        CustomThreadPool.EnqueWork(() => {

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.WriteLine("****First*****");
        });

        CustomThreadPool.EnqueWork(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.WriteLine("****Second*****");
        });

        CustomThreadPool.EnqueWork(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.WriteLine("****Third*****");
        });

        CustomThreadPool.EnqueWork(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.WriteLine("****Fourth*****");
        });

        CustomThreadPool.EnqueWork(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.WriteLine("****Fifth*****");
        });
    }
}

public class CountAutoResentEvent
{
    public void Set()
    {
        _event.Set();
        lock (_sync)
            _countOfSet++;
    }

    public void WaitOne()
    {
        _event.WaitOne();
        lock (_sync)
        {
            _countOfSet--;
            if (_countOfSet > 0)
                _event.Set();
        }
    }

    private AutoResetEvent _event = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private int _countOfSet = 0;
    private object _sync = new object();
}
```

Now, I have few questions:

1. Is my approach full proof?
2. What synchronization mechanism is best suited for this problem and why?
3. How a multithreading expert would deal with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: @Hans Passant: That talks about a different issue in my opinion. And this question has several points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen I'd say it's correct. I like that you have used `ConcurrentQueue` and didn't go about implementing a synchronized queue of your own. That's a mess and will most likely not be as fast as the existing one.

I would only like to note that your custom "signaling mechanism" is actually very similar to a semaphore: a lock that allows more than one thread to enter a critical section. This functionality already exists in the [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) class.

Comment: @Hans Passant: He didn't say it's not correct. He asked it it's correct or not. And why is not semaphore correct? Basically what he implemented is an event with a counter.

Comment: I could solve it using ManualResetEvent and Semaphore (as suggested by Tudor). The question is - the approach that I have taken is it correct?. Secondly, is there easy or the right approach/mechanism to the problem. How would u solve the same problem if u have to?

Comment: @Anand Patel: I would solve it like you did. It seems the most straightforward approach for a simple thread pool and you didn't do any complicated things that can get you into trouble. Like I said, I would probably also try to use a built-in signaling mechanism to reduce the amount of potential errors, but otherwise I would probably have done it the same as you.

Comment: Well, I would have gone with just a semaphore straight off.  If there is a thread-safe count involved, (and here there is), it's almost a definition of a semaphore. Requestor pushes on a work item and signals the semaphore, pool threads wait on the semaphore and then dequeue a work item - no need to check any queue 'count' or 'isEmpty'.   A thread pool is essentially a Producer-Consumer queue for work objects, a 'Computer Science 101' P-C queue uses semaphores, so  why consider using an event at all for this?

Comment: @Martin James - I know of semaphore but I tried to solve the problem by only with - Monitor, ManualResetEvent and AutoResetEvent. I did not realized Semaphore to be the best fit for the solution. As suggested by Tudor and you, I tried semaphore and it worked absolutely fine without any tweaks. Semaphore seems to be the approprite mechanism in this case.

Comment: @Tudor: Marking your response as the answer.

Comment: @Anand Patel: I was glad to help you. :)